# Invalid character in XML transformation

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have an xml file with a tag as shown below

```
<mvaKode>VHØY</mvaKode>
```

I have created a transformer which converts the value inside mvaKode as below

```
<EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>
     <xsl:value-of select="mvaKode"/>
</EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_CODE>
```

But when i do the transformation I am getting the below error

```
An invalid character was found in text content. Error processing resource 'http://dse1xdiapp9142:8082/servlet/org.netbeans....
```

The error is due to the `Ø` character (swedishcharacters) in mvaKode. So it seems like an encoding issue.

Is there any way I could get rid of this error??

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Is your XML is dynamically generated by that servlet or is it a static file?

Comment: The input XML is a static file which includes swedish characters

Comment: When you open that static XML file in a browser, does it show up correctly?

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced using the posted code: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxWZS7U. Please provide a reproducible example and state which processor you're using.

Comment: @Tomalak yes it opens without any issues

Comment: @michael.hor257k I cannot reproduce it in xsltfiddle. It works fine there. Could be something to do with processor may be. I will investigate this abit more any will get back

Comment: Then the way your Java code reads that file from disk and sends it to the client is wrong. Show that code, and a minimal sample of the XML.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks for the support. Appreciate it alot

Comment: @Tomalak thanks for the support. Appreciate it alot

Comment: @Tomalak Its the same as michael has done https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxWZS7U. My complete code works perfectly in XSLT fiddle

Comment: It could be that your processor cannot handle non-ASCII characters. Or (more likely, IMHO) that for some reason your processor thinks the source encoding is such that the character is invalid.

Comment: As I said, the XML and the XSLT are not the issue. The code that *serves* the XML under the `http://dse1xdiapp9142:8082/...` URL is.

Comment: Yes seems that way. i tried adding <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/> to my XSLT. This worked but changing VHØY to VHÅY.

Comment: I will dig a bit deep on this. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to establish whether (a) there is a stored file in which the data is incorrectly encoded, or (b) there is a "misunderstanding" about the encoding, so that the file is encoded with encoding X, but is being decoded with encoding Y. (The cause is almost certainly one of these two options).

If the cause is (a) then you need to (i) repair existing data, and (ii) prevent a recurrence by investigating how the data got corrupted in the first place.

If the cause is (b) then you need to fix configuration settings somewhere, for example in your web server.

From the information given, that's about all we can tell you at this stage, but hopefully it provides you with sufficient lines of enquiry.